# How do emotions influence the language structures we use?

Tags: reference-request, emotion, language, linguistics

**What are the verbal signs of subjectivity?**

I am doing research about the linguistic content of media (debates, talk-show, sport comments). It occurs that once the participant gets nervous or excited, the grammatical structure of the sentences and word choice (growing amount of modal verbs, judgmental adjectives, not politically correct nouns, dynamic verbs) can change.

That is why I am looking for sources that give me some research results about how emotions affect our verbal expressions (e.g., sentence structure, word usage, etc).

My research is in Polish and Dutch.

Comment: I'd be very interested in the outcome of your research. I'm studying how to identify author profile in written documents, and now going to study how spoken and written are related...

Comment: @PaulinaDymalska ngram analysis would be useful. Its being used to settle long time disputes on who made a particular quote in an analytic way and could be used in media discourse as well. You may view http://books.google.com/ngrams/ to get some idea.

Comment: What about semantic analysis using NLTK in Python?

Comment: Perhaps you might be able to get an answer on [linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/). Unfortunately I can't migrate the question there anymore since this question is older than 60 days. In case you ask the question there, consider deleting this one after you have received answers. Also keep us posted if you post there.

Comment: Better yet, ask this question on http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ and then **comment on both questions**, linking them to each other. Then, **when one question gets an accepted an answer, post that answer to the other question and accept it**.

Comment: In my work, I follow the model proposed by Peter Gardenfors (http://www.fil.lu.se/person/PeterGardenfors) in 'Conceptual Spaces: The Geometry of Thought'. Trying to understand how emotions affect verbal expressions, you may find his ideas useful. Peter Gardenfors offers his theory of conceptual representations as a bridge between the precognitive (I guess we could include emotions too) and symbolic (language).

Answer (score 1):

*This is by no means exhaustive, but is a beginning, as these links also provide links.*

[**Journal of Cognitive Neuroscience**](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/jocn.1997.9.2.266)
**A Neural Dissociation within Language: Evidence that the Mental Dictionary Is Part of Declarative Memory, and that Grammatical Rules Are Processed by the Procedural System**

The following study links the effects of emotional arousal on these two memory systems, thus linking the effects of emotional arousal on speech.

**[Effects of emotional arousal on multiple memory systems: Evidence from declarative and procedural](http://learnmem.cshlp.org/content/13/5/650.short) learning

Stephan Steidl, Salwa Mohi-uddin, and Adam K. Anderson**

**[How Emotion Shapes Behavior: Feedback, Anticipation, and Reflection, Rather Than Direct Causation](http://psr.sagepub.com/content/11/2/167.short)

Roy F. Baumeister  Kathleen D. Vohs  C. Nathan DeWall  Liqing Zhang**

**[A review of paradoxical performance effects: Choking under pressure in sports and mental tests](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ejsp.2420160405/abstract)

Roy F Baumeister  Carolin J. Showers**

Choking under pressure refers to the failure of a person to perform tasks that they are highly skilled in, when placed under pressure to perform. This could well apply to people speaking on a talk show.

This study shows the effects of various emotions on the actual voice quality, which is also useful.

**[THE EFFECTS OF EMOTIONS ON VOICE QUALITY](http://eclub.unige.ch/system/files/biblio/1999_Johnstone_ICPS.pdf)

Tom Johnstone and Klaus R. Scherer
University of Geneva**

Comment: Skippy, thanks for all of your effort on this, but I don't think any of these actually answer the question.

Comment: I appreciate that you are attacking this difficult unanswered question with gusto! :) However, it seems like you hit on some of the points, but the `grammatical structure of the sentences and word choice` portion (which I think is important, and why I think the question went unanswered) doesn't seem to be here anywhere.  If I'm wrong, please include quotes from the papers indicating that aspect of it.

Comment: It's fine that you did that, but I think tying it together with some additional prose to indicate the lack of direct evidence would make it a stronger answer.